# Google Apps - This account cannot be accessed because we could not parse the login request

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0

I want to do SSO through SAMLResponse, which  is generated after receiving the authrequest from Google. But with outlook, I have found that error:

> Google Apps - This account cannot be accessed because we could not parse the login request.

Email address and cert is hide due to security.

SAML response is given below:

```
<samlp:Response xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
                xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
                xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"
                Destination="https://www.google.com/a/dev.authen2cate.com/acs"
                ID="gahbmmoclhngahdkmgijdmfnjoajnonpfhojkdii"
                InResponseTo="eopmnjkanijnhaooojjipjcfiapacicmgfnkmhmj"
                IssueInstant="2014-01-09T07:43:26Z"
                Version="2.0"
                >
    <saml:Issuer xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">http://debug-ad.authen2cate.com</saml:Issuer>
    <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <SignedInfo>
            <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
            <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
            <Reference URI="">
                <Transforms>
                    <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                </Transforms>
                <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                <DigestValue>XmexZKht13MLScVBPcrd+Dp1+jw=</DigestValue>
            </Reference>
        </SignedInfo>
        <SignatureValue>Z5u23PrImHZndHYkMbJtj4+n1F7bW3G3GLwogR6wYDLi2vFwt1EzKWSd5ATJjRlTnQT11W8+Wf8P
mlVthcvuQeZY9/jijoOT88y/Li4+B9hgmpnZI6WmgZWtOdRmAUvTvUGF3fR13iUxuttmWCNG+0Bf
bwxj5pnkQOsXVdnDgY0rkN9qe2XxFx3VFuFcoEE3dQVTxLT4xZBsjX+N/ao9b/+tEwQHvdwHsAr7
hDaQWxkSXT5/T8+0Lljtv1NZ4GZHkI59i3f2j8UQ3LR19LfY0EykEvWCHP3x5EdVSarkzYyQOddB
R3480a6KQjJOOw+Hhsu/tL+bWrw2sJ7HpUXVkw==</SignatureValue>
        <KeyInfo>
            <X509Data>
                <X509Certificate>MIIEzzCCA7egAwIBAgI............</X509Certificate>
            </X509Data>
            <KeyValue>
                <RSAKeyValue>
                    <Modulus>wB4Uiws31Hjx0folWTMCJDrGFniKajRUgTgcVjNo8r/MUoWQEEh7lH7fOBPbdcREUQFllBMNLiFX
uSpKIsQPZVzPOwaWkWkBjTTISmG+nz9FCgOsyZnkWc0HFprC8Eg7x6I2TfPWZ1lKJhIiBWOI35m5
z9Xcr/LhleOPrDq66yTeCHABej4xs5kxFRGdgYtm9fdTQ78psHJseJm7hP6DbVCtVlBkesq7AAd6
r7B9Rj8nEQk4ZVtQWoo/4soF+nFwW6u4UyaLKswystI+B40XTizv4pNYQM6U6XZ+eoYJxTGlW2sU
gkeMWvYgM6BbNu5ex2i2DzTq3/lS8VnTpZEMWQ==</Modulus>
                    <Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>
                </RSAKeyValue>
            </KeyValue>
        </KeyInfo>
    </Signature>
    <samlp:Status>
        <samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success" />
    </samlp:Status>
    <saml:Assertion xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
                    ID="gahbmmoclhngahdkmgijdmfnjoajnonpfhojkdii"
                    IssueInstant="2014-01-09T07:43:26Z"
                    Version="2.0"
                    >
        <saml:Issuer>http://debug-ad.authen2cate.com</saml:Issuer>
        <saml:Subject>
            <saml:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified">email_address</saml:NameID>
            <saml:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
                <saml:SubjectConfirmationData InResponseTo="eopmnjkanijnhaooojjipjcfiapacicmgfnkmhmj"
                                              NotOnOrAfter="2014-01-10T07:43:26Z"
                                              Recipient="https://www.google.com/a/dev.authen2cate.com/acs"
                                              />
            </saml:SubjectConfirmation>
        </saml:Subject>
        <saml:Conditions NotBefore="2014-01-09T07:38:25Z"
                         NotOnOrAfter="2014-01-10T07:43:26Z"
                         >
            <saml:AudienceRestriction>
                <saml:Audience>https://www.google.com/a/dev.authen2cate.com/acs</saml:Audience>
            </saml:AudienceRestriction>
        </saml:Conditions>
        <saml:AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2014-01-09T07:43:26Z">
            <saml:AuthnContext>
                <saml:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:unspecified</saml:AuthnContextClassRef>
            </saml:AuthnContext>
        </saml:AuthnStatement>
    </saml:Assertion>
</samlp:Response>
```

Comment: I think that you're missing the relaystate. How are you generating the response?